# Flutter firebase Document Id does not exist, but it do exist

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have added to firestore, when i try to update it says id doesnt exist , but it do exist. How can i solve this?

[productModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsbJc.png)

[add to firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuHhg.png)

[the list that was added to firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPCvQ.png)

[fetching the products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJHnF.png)

[updating collection 'products'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U64n.png)

[output in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jXEF.png)

[cloud firestore where id does exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tODVW.png)

```
enter code here
Future<void> addProductsToFirestore() async {
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
QuerySnapshot productsSnapshot =
    await firestore.collection('products').get();
if (productsSnapshot.docs.isEmpty) {
  try {
    // Get a reference to the products collection
    CollectionReference productsCollection =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products');

    // Loop through each product in _productsList and add it to Firestore
    for (var product in _productsList) {
      await productsCollection.add(product.toMap());
    }

    print('Products added to Firestore successfully!');
  } catch (error) {
    print('Error adding products to Firestore: $error');
    rethrow;
  }
} else {
  return;
}
```

}

```
 static final List<ProductModel> _productsList = [
ProductModel(
    id: 'beetroot-juice',
    title: 'rödbetsjuice'.toUpperCase(),
    imgUrl: 'assets/images/juice/beetroot_liter.jpg',
    productCategoryName: 'juicer'.toUpperCase(),
    prices: {
      '25-CL': 25,
      '50-CL': 50,
      '75-CL': 65,
      '100-CL-1L': 80,
    }),
ProductModel(
    id: 'blueberry-juice',
    title: 'blåbärsjuice'.toUpperCase(),
    imgUrl: 'assets/images/juice/blueberry_liter.jpg',
    productCategoryName: 'juicer'.toUpperCase(),
    prices: {
      '25-CL': 25,
      '50-CL': 50,
      '75-CL': 65,
      '100-CL-1L': 80,
    }),`
```

`

```
class ProductModel with ChangeNotifier {
   final String id, title, imgUrl, productCategoryName;
   final Map<String, int> prices; // Map to store prices for             different volumes
 final bool isPopular;

 ProductModel({
this.isPopular = false,
required this.id,
required this.title,
required this.imgUrl,
required this.productCategoryName,
required this.prices,
 });

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
return {
  'id': id,
  'title': title,
  'imgUrl': imgUrl,
  'productCategoryName': productCategoryName,
  'prices': prices,
  'isPopular': isPopular,
 };
}

factory ProductModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
 return ProductModel(
  id: map['id'],
  title: map['title'],
  imgUrl: map['imgUrl'],
  productCategoryName: map['productCategoryName'],
  prices: Map<String, int>.from(map['prices']),
  isPopular: map['isPopular'] ?? false,
  );
 }
```

}

```
class _ProductWidgetState extends State<ProductWidget> {
final bool _isLoading = false;
String title = '';
String? imgUrl;
String price = '0';

int groupValue = 1;
String? id;
late final ProductModel productModel;

@override
void initState() {
// getProductsData();
//fetchProducts();
super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 Size size = Utils(context).getScreenSize;
//price = 'widget.product.price';
 final productProviders = Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context);
 List<ProductModel> allProducts =      productProviders.getFetchedProducts;
 final productModel = Provider.of<ProductModel>(context);

// LOOK NY KOD
int price;
String volume;
final prices = productModel.prices;
final volumes = prices.keys.toList();

// Assuming volumes are sorted in ascending order, pick the first volume as the default
final defaultVolume = volumes.first;

return Material(
    color: Theme.of(context).cardColor.withOpacity(0.9),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
    child: InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => EditProductsScreen(
              id: productModel.id,
              title: productModel.title,
              // price: productModel.prices.toString(),
              productCat: productModel.productCategoryName,
              imgUrl: productModel.imgUrl,

              isPopular: productModel.isPopular,
              prices: prices,
            ),
          ),
        );
        print('Document ID: ${productModel.id}');
        print('Document TITLE: ${productModel.title}');
        print('Document PRODUCTCAT:             ${productModel.productCategoryName}');
        print('Document PRICES: ${productModel.prices}');
        print('Document POPULAR: ${productModel.isPopular}');
        print('Document IMGURL: ${productModel.imgUrl}');
      },




class EditProductsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 static const routeName = '/EditProductsScreen';
 const EditProductsScreen({
 super.key,
 required this.id,
 required this.title,
 required this.productCat,
 required this.imgUrl,
 required this.isPopular,
 required this.prices,
  });
 final String id, title, productCat, imgUrl;

 final bool isPopular;

final Map<String, dynamic> prices;
@override
State<EditProductsScreen> createState() =>        _EditProductsScreenState();
}

class _EditProductsScreenState extends State<EditProductsScreen>      {
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 String _catValue = 'juice'.toUpperCase();
 int _groupValue = 1;
 bool _isPopular = false;

 File? _pickedImage;
 late String? _imgUrl;
 bool _isLoading = false;
 int val = 1;
 var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

 late final TextEditingController _titleController,
  _priceController,
  _priceControllerOneLitre,
  _priceControllerTwentyFive,
  _priceControllerFifty,
  _priceControllerSeventyFive;

@override
void initState() {
// set the price and title initial values and init the     controllers
 _titleController = TextEditingController(text: widget.title);
// _priceController = TextEditingController(text: widget.price);
 _priceControllerOneLitre =
    TextEditingController(text: widget.prices['100-CL-      1L'].toString());
_priceControllerTwentyFive =
    TextEditingController(text: widget.prices['25-     CL'].toString());
_priceControllerFifty =
    TextEditingController(text: widget.prices['50-     CL'].toString());
_priceControllerSeventyFive =
    TextEditingController(text: widget.prices['75-     CL'].toString());
// set the variables
 _isPopular = widget.isPopular;
 _catValue = widget.productCat;

 _imgUrl = widget.imgUrl;

 super.initState();
```

}

```
 @override
 void dispose() {
  _titleController.dispose();
  _priceController.dispose();
  _priceControllerOneLitre.dispose();
  _priceControllerTwentyFive.dispose();
  _priceControllerFifty.dispose();
  _priceControllerSeventyFive.dispose();
  super.dispose();
 }



 Future<void> _updateProduct() async {
  final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
  final galenRef = db.collection('products').doc(widget.id);

  if (isValid) {
  _formKey.currentState!.save();

   try {
     setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
     });

    String priceOneLitre = _priceControllerOneLitre.text;
    String priceTwentyFive = _priceControllerTwentyFive.text;
    String priceFifty = _priceControllerFifty.text;
    String priceSeventyFive = _priceControllerSeventyFive.text;

    DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot;
    try {
      docSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('products')
          .doc(widget.id)
          .get();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error getting document: $e');
      rethrow;
    }
    final docSnapshots = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('products')
        .doc(widget.id)
        .get();

    print(docSnapshots.exists); // Should be true if document exists
    //await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();
    if (!docSnapshot.exists) {
      throw 'Document with ID ${widget.id} does not exist!';
    }
    try {
      galenRef.update({
        'id': widget.id,
        'imgUrl': _pickedImage == null ? widget.imgUrl : _imgUrl,
        'isPopular': _isPopular,
        'prices': {
          '100-CL-1L': priceOneLitre,
          '25-CL': priceTwentyFive,
          '50-CL': priceFifty,
          '75-CL': priceSeventyFive,
        },
        "productCategoryName": _catValue,
        "title": _titleController.text,
      }).then((value) => print("DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!"),
          onError: (e) => print("Error updating document $e"));
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error updating document: $e');
      rethrow;
    }
```

i am trying to update a collection in firestore, but it doesnt work

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: sorry, i changed it

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).